# How to handle similar urls in rails 4 explicitly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

i am trying to make more semantic url like below:-

```
  //with one params
  get 'location/:location' => 'home#show_by_location', as: :show_by_location
  //with two params
  get ':location/:name/'  => 'home#show_details' , as: :show_details
```

they are almost similar  but they are not working as second url never gets called as rails think they are same and hence calls only first one(*as expected*).**So how can i treat both of them differently**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order and use a [constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) to tell rails that `:location` cannot be the string `'location'`:

```
get ':location/:name/' => 'home#show_details', constraints: { location: /^(location)/ }, as: :show_details
get 'location/:location' => 'home#show_by_location', as: :show_by_location
```